# Can not add `System.Windows.Forms` reference to my WCF service library

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I can't add `System.Windows.Forms` to my WCF service library.

I want to return a `List<ListViewItem>` from my method `GetItems(string path)`, I also tried to add reference of `System.Windows.Forms` but not found it looks like WCF service library doesn't support it.

Any ideas how could I do it?

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IFileManager
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<ListViewItem> collection(string path);
    }
}
```

This is my `Item.cs` class:

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
  [DataContract]
  public class Item
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string name;
    [DataMember]
    public string path;
    [DataMember]
    public long size;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime date;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to create a windows form application and use WCF service as a client. Then you can call its methots and show the result in your form. The purpose of WCF is not showing any data to users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF is designed to be an **interoperable** service platform, therefore I would recommend **NOT** to use .NET specific datatypes like `ListViewItem` as the return types from your service. After all, what will a PHP or Ruby client do with such an object??

Instead: use your `Item` class, return a list of those from your WCF service, and leave it up to the calling application to convert that into `ListViewItem`s as needed....

Also: returning `ListViewItem` from your WCF service would **severely** limit that service's functionality. If some client would like to get that data, but present it in some other way (not in a `ListView`), they couldn't use that service call anymore..... by returning **just data elements** (like your `Item`) class, you leave it up to the caller to decide what to do with that data, and how to possibly show it on screen. I think that's a **good thing** and shouldn't be changed!

Comment: so you say i use `List<Item>` an list of the item class i created! right ?

Comment: @MurHafSoz: yes - return a `List<Item>` from your service - and whatever the caller wants to do with that information (do some calculation, store it, display it on screen) and in which form that caller wants to display it should be the caller's responsibility - the service just provides the data - nothing more

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to return form controls or list of controls from a WCF service. The return types can be Datacontract , Messagecontract, .NET primitive types and the types that can be serialized over the wire.

WCF services are supposed to expose data not UI controls. It depends upon client application to display that data in whatever form. You should create windows client to display data in listview.